# Getting error on using other project node modules

Tags: typescript, package.json, tsconfig

I'm getting 'cannot found module' error when I try to import other project module.

Please look at `@core` from the tsconfig below:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "../../",
    "removeComments": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@core/*": ["../../core/node_modules/*"], <<< core is shared lib in our project
      "@app/*": ["src/*"],
      "@consumer": ["../../event-broker/core-event-consumer/src/index.js"],
    },
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "typeRoots": ["src/@types", "node_modules/@types", "../../core/node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "__test__/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

The code I use to import core:

```
import winston from '@core/winston'
```

Lint gets what i'm trying to import but build doesn't generate winston module.
I also used symlink to build(`link-module-alias` package).
Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "prepublishOnly": "yarn build",
    "postinstall": "mkdir -p dist/service/cms/src && link-module-alias",
    ...
    "dev": "tsc --p ./tsconfig.json -w & nodemon ./src/index.ts",
    "build": "rm -rf dist/* && tsc --p ./tsconfig.json",
    "start": "node dist/service/cms/src/index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "link-module-alias": "^1.2.0",
    ...
  },
  "main": "dist/service/cms/src/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "_moduleAliases": {
      "@app": "dist/service/cms/src",
      "@consumer": "dist/event-broker/core-event-consumer/src/index.js",
      "@core": "dist/core/node_modules"
  },
  "nodemonConfig": {
    "ignore": [
      "**/*.test.ts",
      "**/*.spec.ts",
      ".git",
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "watch": [
      "src"
    ],
    "exec": "ts-node --files ./src/index.ts",
    "ext": "ts, js"
  }
}
```

As a workaround, I've able to find module on build by specifying `winston.js` file in actual module folder but also getting many typeerror including below:

```
../../core/core-node_modules/winston/dist/winston/profiler.js:7:1 - error TS9005: Declaration emit for this file requires using private name 'Profiler'. An explicit type annotation may unblock declaration emit.

7 'use strict';
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Or I need to specify module file in tsconfig and package.json but I can't do that every time core packages is added.

Clearly, below part is working though,

```
  "paths": {
      ...
      "@app/*": ["src/*"],
      ...
  }
```